# React Native: How to hide an element other than conditional render?

Tags: react-native

How do I hide/show a View element other than conditional rendering (which would render the view every time) ?
I tried setting the Height of the View to 0/1 but it doesn't work on IOS and defaults to the height of inner children.

I need this to show the menu which would slide from top to bottom. This menu is also an overlay with absolute coordinates.

```
<View style={styles.container}>        
    <Animated.View style={[styles.toggleMenu]} >
        <MenuScreen onPress={()=>{this.toggleMenu()}}/>
    </Animated.View>
</View>

Styles

container: {
flex: 1,  
backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
borderRadius: 8,
borderColor: '#000000'
},

toggleMenu:{
position: 'absolute',
left: 0,
top: 0,
width:WindowSize.width,
height: 0,
backgroundColor: '#2b3643',
opacity:0.95,
padding:0,
overflow: 'hidden'
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at Animated in React Native, you can perform hide / show with animated, with or without a transition (with or without a timed animation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `overflow: "hidden"` on your element, which should allow the height property to properly "hide" children.

Note that there may be some conflicts using `height` with other flexbox properties, which I'd need your code to diagnose.

Fun fact: the reason you may be having trouble on iOS and not Android is because on Android all Views inherently hide children that are outside of their boundaries. This functionality does not exist by default on iOS.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have set overflow:'hidden' but it still seems to conflict with some other style and still shows the inner content when height is set to 0. I have edited my post to include the code..

Comment: Thanks, overflow:'hidden' solves the problem in IOS. For Android tough setting height to 0 doesn't work so trying with a workaround by setting it to 0.1 instead.

Comment: make sure you don't have any padding on the parent view you are trying to hide. Removing padding solved my issue